# java.lang.StackOverflowError in MergeSort

Tags: java, sorting, stack-overflow, mergesort

```
public class MergeSort
{
public static double[] MergeSort(double[] a){
    if(a.length < 1){
        return new double[0];
    }
    else if(a.length == 1){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        double[] l = Teiler(a, false);
        double[] r = Teiler(a, true);
        return Fueger(MergeSort(l), MergeSort(r));
    }
}
...
}
```

public static double[] Fueger(double[] a, double[] b):
returns an array of doubles containing all numbers from a and b in correct order.

public static double[] Teiler(double[] a, boolean l):
returns half of the elements (the first half, if l is false, second half, if l is true)

Fueger and Teiler work perfectly well, but MergeSort always gives java.lang.StackOverflowError, even though the recursion should be terminates as soon as the array is empty or just contains one element.
What is the problem?

Thanks for your help

Here is Fueger:

```
public static double[] Fueger(double[] a, double[] b){
    double[] hilf = new double[a.length + b.length];
    int i = 0;
    while((a.length != 0) && (b.length != 0)){
        if(a[0] < b[0]){
            hilf[i] = a[0];
            a = Weg(a);
        }
        else{
            hilf[i] = b[0];
            b = Weg(b);
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(a.length != 0){
        for(double x : a){
            hilf[i] = x;
            a = Weg(a);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(b.length != 0){
        for(double x : b){
            hilf[i] = x;
            b = Weg(b);
            i++;
        }
    }
    return hilf;
}
```

Teiler:

```
public static double[] Teiler(double[] a, boolean r){
    double[] hilf;
    int x = 0;
    if(r == false){
        hilf = new double[(int) a.length / 2];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++){
            hilf[x] = a[i];
            i ++;
        }
    }
    else{
        hilf = new double[(int) (a.length / 2) + 1];
        for(int i = a.length / 2; i < a.length; i++){
            hilf[x] = a[i];
            i ++;
        } 
    }
    return hilf;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace (the whole error text printed when the StackOverflow happens)? Please post it here.

Comment: I doubt whether the stack trace would help.  I suspect it's just a large number of  lines of `MergeSort` calling itself.  It would be far more useful to see the `Teiler` method - I've a feeling that's where the error probably is.

Comment: at MergeSort.MergeSort(MergeSort.java:11)
 at MergeSort.MergeSort(MergeSort.java:13)
 at MergeSort.MergeSort(MergeSort.java:13)

Comment: And I just added Fueger so you can have a look

Comment: @TobiasWeißberg Why `a.length / 2 + 1`? What happens when `a.length == 2`?

Comment: Yeah, the error is in the `else` clause of `Teiler`.  As kennytm pointed out.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. Or just `println` the input array at the start of the method. You'll find the error. PS it's easier for SO answerers if you follow Java style conventions. Method names should startWithLowerCase.

Comment: I also think the problem is the `a.length / 2 + 1`, if you consider a list of 2 elements `Teiler(a, true)` returns an array of length 2 (even though it fills only the first element). I think you can work around the issue by `(a.length / 2) + (a.length % 2)`

Comment: Why did you remove  `Teiler` after kennytm and I both pointed out that that's where the problem was?  Are you trying to make  it difficult for people to answer?

Comment: Second point: Have you tried to work in-place? You are making *a lot* of copies.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working!

Comment: @AimeeBorda That  is the correct answer, and if you post it as an answer, I will upvote it.  Basically,  if `a` has length 2 and `r` is `true`, then `Teiler` currently returns an array of length 2.  This traps the recursion in an endless loop.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` twice in the `Teiler` method (once in the `for` loop, and then again within the loop)? And also you are not incrementing `x` at all there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the Teiler method. Consider a list of length 2, the else branch creates a list of length 2 rather than 1 (even though it fills only the first element). Consequently, trapping the recursion in an endless loop. You can easily fix this issue by adding the last element only if the length is odd:

```
public static double[] Teiler(double[] a, boolean r){
   double[] hilf;
   int x = 0;
   if(r == false){
       hilf = new double[(int) a.length / 2];
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++){
           hilf[x] = a[i];
           i ++;
       }
   } else{
       hilf = new double[(int) (a.length / 2) + (a.length % 2)];
       for(int i = a.length / 2; i < a.length; i++){
           hilf[x] = a[i];
           i ++;
       } 
   }
   return hilf;
}
```

Comment: This is absolutely valid way of doing that - but I like to write such things as something like `int bottomSize = a.length/2; int topSize = a.length-bottomSize;` which kind of self-documents the that we care about leftovers from other half.

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski fair enough :)